# Inserting spaces between numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider a string:

```
12345678
```

The desired output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

How can this be split using JavaScript?

Comment: please define what do you mean by split

Comment: this must be a trick question...

Comment: What should be the result for the string "1234567891011..."?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

split to what? 
if you want to split each character to array element, use javascript split() method :

```
var str = "12345678";
var arr = str.split("");
```

Answer (score 14):

No need for jQuery to split a string.  Use pure javascript.

```
var s = "12345678";
var letters = s.split('');  // results in [ '1', '2', '3', .... ]
```

Answer (score 14):

```
'12345678'.split('').join(' ');
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use straight Javascript for this:

```
var string = "12345678";
var parts  = string.split('');
```

Comment: Maybe he means split it up and get each digit out.

Answer (score 2):

no jquery needed, you can split string using regular javascript split function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="12345678";

var splittedStr = str.split("");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = "12345678";
  $('#s').html(s);
  var letters = s.split('').join(' ');
  $('#letters').html(letters);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id='s'></label><br/><label id='letters'></label>
```

Comment: output will be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Answer (score -1):

My guess is he just wants to put spaces in between the numbers. How about:

```
str = "1234567890";
var splitStringArray = str.split("");
var finalString = "";

for(var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
    finalString += splitStringArray[i];

    if (i < splitStringArray.length-1) {
        finalString += " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yuck! Use `str.split('').join(' ')`.

Comment: loops can be terribly inefficient, if possible try to avoid using them.  str.split('').join(' ');  will work the same.  If you are to use a loop consider defining the i, and splitStringArray.length outside, or better yet use a reverse while(i--)  http://blogs.sun.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a